# Pushing items to same array Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following array, which is not really how it should be.

```
"people": [
{"name": "Bob"},
{"occupation": "King"}
]
```

If I put this data in a table, the info goes along a diagonal line, and not along the same line, like a normal table.

This result is generated by my routing code here:

```
user.people.push({'name': body.name });
user.occupation.push({'occupation': body.occupation });
```

I have tried this:

```
for (i = 0; i < people.length; i){
user.people[i].push({'name': body.name });
user.occupation[i].push({'occupation': body.occupation});
}
```

But this stops my POST request from working.

**EDIT**

This is done using Node. My schema in my user.js contains the following lines.

```
people: [{
name: String,
occupation: String
}]
```

In addition, my ejs rendered table is like so:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < user.people.length; i++) {%>
<tr>
<td><%=user.people[i].name %></td>
<td><%=user.people[i].occupation %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Essentially what I want my array to look like is:

```
people: [{
name: Bob,
occupation: King
}]
```

So after testing, in my instance the solution turned out to be the following:

```
user.people.push(
{
    'name': body.name,
    'occupation': body.occupation
});
```

which goes to show that ample info was provided to solve this issue.

Comment: It is. But it's also kind of funny looking.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information about your code to understand why it's stopping post request.

Comment: What POST request, what kind of table? HTML, SQL?

Comment: I'm, uhm, what are you doing, and why?

Comment: Could it have something to do with that "user" does not contain "occupation", but "person" does? which means that it should be user.person.occupation instead of just user.occupation?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "people", not person.

Comment: No, user defines my larger schema. I tried taking it out and got a render error.

Comment: The `people` array in your most recent edit is invalid. Quotes are missing? Also, it is different in structure from what you first provided, at the top of your question. There `name` is in a different array element than `occupation`. Please make your question consistent, and provide valid object notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are accessing occupation, you call it through people[i].occupation:

```
<td><%=user.people[i].occupation %></td>
```

You need to do the same when editing it, like so:

```
user.people[i].occupation.push({'occupation': body.occupation});
```

or something like it.

**EDIT:**

Actually, come to think of it

```
user.people[i].push({'occupation': body.occupation});
```

Should do the trick.

Sorry, it's a little late over here.